# Ionic cordova app working on all browsers and IOS 9, but not anymore on IOS 8 [freezes without error]

Tags: ios, cordova, ios8

I have an Ionic application that worked well under iOS 8.

Now I have updated some code and included the network information plugin and updated to **cordova-ios-3.9.2.**

I have done some debugging for two days, but I get no errors, not in Xcode and not when I inspect the app using safari webinspector.

However, the app does not work anymore under iOS 8.1. It does work under iOS 9 and all Android versions.

I know it is a vague issue, I hope to find someone who can help. Maybe someone who knows the difference between iOS 8 and 9?

we are using the following plugins:

- android.support.v4
- com.internrocket.plugins.statusbarcolor
- com.ionic.keyboard
- cordova-plugin-console
- cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview
- cordova-plugin-datepicker
- cordova-plugin-device
- cordova-plugin-network-information (this one is new between te previous and this release, but I think it does not break it)
- cordova-plugin-splashscreen
- cordova-plugin-statusbar
- cordova-plugin-velda-devicefeedback
- cordova-plugin-whitelist
- cordova-plugin-x-toast
- cordova-plugin-inappbrowser

The changes in the code are minor and well tested on all major browser, plus I get no error in the safari web-inspector, plus it works under iOS 9 so I do not suspect them.

Also strange is that the layout looks strange under IOS8. Maybe it is a css error? I have no idea if this is even possible?

Any help is appreciated!

EDIT: 
 What I have tried: use the previous ionic code with **ios-cordova 3.9.2.** This works. Also on iOS 8.1

Comment: Wasn't there some breaking changes to the way iOS handled webviews that necessitated Cordova to update the webview handling ?

Comment: Please explain me more!

Comment: You are likely loading your assets (CSS and Javascript) from the web. This is not best practice. Load as many assets as you can locally &ndash from the device itself.  Otherwise you NEED to say what is not working as you expect it.

Comment: We found the issue! We used autoprefixing (to prefix css with for example -webkit-). This is a gulp plugin, which we updated. Afterwards it only autoprefixed for ios 9. Now we have set it to IOS 7 and it is working again. Took me 2 days to find out :S
Never thought that a css issue could break your hybrid app completely!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I had a similar issue, and I use this plugin:
https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-autoprefixer

The issue was that this plugin recommends the following implementation:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');

gulp.task('default', () =>
    gulp.src('src/app.css')
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['last 2 versions'],
            cascade: false
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
);
```

What happened is that two weeks ago, iOS 9.3 was released, thus removing support for iOS 8 and breaking my app, and having some really irate customers.

The fix was to specify the versions I needed supported.

```
gulp.task('default', () =>
    gulp.src('src/app.css')
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['ios_saf >= 7', 'Chrome >= 42'],
            cascade: false
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
);
```

Hope that helps someone out there!

Comment: That is how we also ended up doing it! :)

Answer (score 0):

The issues was with the CSS prefixes. Between releases we had accidentially removed some of them. Without the -webkit- css prefix the ios app breaks without warning or error.